# Count QString arguments

Tags: qt, qstring

Do you know how to get the count of possible arguments in a `QString`?

I want to do something like:

```
int argumentCount = countArguments(QString("This is the %1 argument, this is the %2 one")`);
```

where the result should be `argumentCount == 2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and `QString::count` function:

```
QString str1("%1%2 test test %3 %4 %555");
int n = str1.count(QRegExp("%\\d+"));//n == 5
```

**Update:**
Because QString's arg numbers can be in 1-99 range this reg-exp can be used:

```
QString str1("%1%2 test test %3 %4 %555");
int n = str1.count(QRegExp("%\\d{1,2}(?!\\d)"));//n == 4
```

Comment: wow. i really need to learn more about them ...*sight*
one last question ... the argument range for `QString::arg()` is %1-99; how to do that?

Comment: sure :) [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info) is an excellent place to get started.